# How do you format dates within MS Access Queries to prevent the US/UK issue

Tags: ms-access, date

How do I ensure that I pick up the right number of records when filtering for dates within an Access Query:

```
SELECT ID, REF, SalesDate, DCount("ID","tblRecords"," Ref='" & [Ref] & "' AND [SalesDate]=#" & format([SalesDate],"yyyy/mm/dd") & "#") as EXPR1 from tblCurrent
```

It picks up the date ok if it cannot be misconstrued such as 28-04-12, but if it is 04-06-12 it doesn't pick it up as it's assuming it's the wrong way around.

Note that this query is not created on the fly or generated from a form etc...

Comment: For anyone working on legacy .mdb Access databases (eg. Access 97). As the accepted answer points out, format dates in US format (`mm/dd/yyyy`) or ISO international format (`yyyy-mm-dd`). Strongly lean towards ISO format to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I either use yyyy/mm/dd for dates in VBA:

```
#" & Format([SalesDate],"yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```

Or parameters, for building queries.

EDIT re additional information

Seeing you are using SQL server, I suggest you use a derived table, which you may find faster, for example:

```
SELECT dbo_Table_1.ADate, ACount FROM dbo_Table_1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.ADate,Count(*) As ACount 
           FROM  dbo_Table_1 As a GROUP BY a.ADate) b
ON dbo_Table_1.Adate=b.ADate
```

EDIT re discussion

```
SELECT * FROM dbo_vwRecordsCurrent As t 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT a.OpptyIncentiveModifiedDate, a.DataSetID, Count(*) AS ACount 
   FROM dbo_vwRecordsHistorical AS a 
   WHERE a.OpportunityIgnored = True 
   GROUP BY a.OpptyIncentiveModifiedDate, a.DataSetID) AS h 
ON t.OpptyIncentiveModifiedDate = h.OpptyIncentiveModifiedDate 
AND t.DataSetID = h.DataSetID
```

I have aliased your tables as the names are very long, so to me, it is more readable to use aliases on the outer sql. They are essential in the inner sql. It is not a good idea to alias a derived table with the name of an existing table.

Comment: It doesn't work, very frustrating.  Don't think I can use parameters as it's picking up the value from a field in the query.

Comment: Where are you running this and what is your sql?

Comment: BTW, I tested format with a query in the design window and it works for me. how is it not working for you? Do you have nulls?

Comment: The SQL for the field is posted in the description.  This query is in an Access front-end with SQL Server backend.  The date is stored as datetime.

Comment: Not everything translates well to SQL Server. I have added a different approach.

Comment: Can I add additional criteria to the 'ON dbo_Table_1.Adate=b.ADate'?

Comment: Probably, that is one reason I was asking for the sql. I will open a chat window.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14267/discussion-between-remou-and-asystemoverload)

Comment: Thank you for the time you've put into this Remou.