# Why do I sometimes see a date surrounded by #, as in #date#, in vba?

Tags: vba

I came across this vba code recently that someone else had written

```
EffectiveDate >=  "#" & datOnLevelDate & "# "
```

Can someone tell me the purpose of the "#" on either side of the date?

Comment: Are you missing a double quote at the beginning? As it is, this expression won't compile.

Comment: I think so and I'll probably have to fix that, but I'm still curious as to why the # signs are needed and what purpose they serve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the expression is constructing a dynamic SQL query for use in Microsoft Access, because in Access, [date literals are enclosed in number signs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/where-clause-HA001231526.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ShippedDate = #5/10/96#;
```

Comment: This is true. This is code that was written in access to do just that. so if you want to compare dates or do math with dates, at least when in access, I take it you must enclose the date in #s?

Comment: The linked article says "Be sure to enclose your date literals with the number sign (#)", so I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to include that quote. Is there any reason that you can think of why it won't work now?

Comment: I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is the vba delimiter to indicate that "date" is in a date format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Oddly, my internet searches were coming up empty. What happens if I take them off?

Comment: Your date would probably be picked up as a string, which could cause you problems in a different context. I say you give it a try and see !

Comment: The pound signs on either side of a data value is more common in Microsoft Access queries. [Here's an example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609944/how-do-you-format-dates-within-ms-access-queries-to-prevent-the-us-uk-issue)