# conversion error from string en vba, insert from vba to firebird

Tags: excel, vba, firebird

I have the following insert from vba to firebird and I can't get it to run ,

the problem is the date in the database is timestamp

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MOVPROD (CONSECUTIVO,FECHA,PRODUCTO,TIENDA,CAJA,USUARIO,VENDEDOR,TIPOMOV,REFERENCIA,CANTIDAD) VALUES ( '" & vDB(i, 1) & "','" & Now & "','" & vDB(i, 2) & "','" & vDB(i, 3) & "','" & vDB(i, 3) & "','000','NA','01','" & vDB(i, 4) & "','" & vDB(i, 5) & "')"
```

Any idea how I could correctly insert into the database?

Comment: Have you tried using the `#` sign for the date field instead of single quotes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021604/why-do-i-sometimes-see-a-date-surrounded-by-as-in-date-in-vba

Comment: The most correct way is using of a query with parameters. It is also protects from SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the timestamp:

```
... ','" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.0000") & "','" ...
```

or, if this is via ODBC, use a date/time string expression:

```
... ',#" & Format(Now, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#,'" ...
```